# taking snapshot of a remote machine

Tags: java, awtrobot

How can I take the snapshot of the remote computer using the `Robot` class?

Comment: The robot class will only work on the local machine. To access a remote machine you need to have something running on that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [thread](http://www.ehow.com/how_7590206_capture-remote-system-using-java.html) will get you started on how to take screenshot of remote system using Robot.